# what is the mechanism use in CI-CD process for Magento2 cloud?

Tags: magento2, deployment, cloud

Like jenkins is automation server, SonarQube for code code quality we can integrate this thing with normal git or any versioning control tool. for our CI-CD process.

SO what mechanism used in Magento2 cloud project for CI-CD?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't used this, from what I could find in the documentation that

> Magento Commerce Cloud is Git driven. Deploying Magento Commerce Cloud is part of your Git push processes for branches.

So basically git based deploy scripts with webhooks.

I suggest you check https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/discover-deploy.html for details regarding the deployment process:

> The build and deploy process is slightly different for each plan:
>
> Starter plans—For the Integration environment, every active branch
> builds and deploys to a full environment for access and testing. Fully
> test your code after merging to the staging branch. To launch your
> site, push staging to master to deploy to the Production environment.
> You have full access to all branches through the Project Web Interface
> and the CLI commands.
>
> Pro plans—For the Integration environment, every active branch builds
> and deploys to a full environment for access and testing. You must
> merge your code to the integration branch before you can merge to the
> Staging environment and then the Production environment. You can merge
> to the Staging and Production environments using the Project Web
> Interface or using SSH and Magento Cloud CLI commands.

This just a brief excerpt, but the page offers valuable information regarding the deployment process, especially https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/discover-deploy.html#cloud-deploy-over-phases.